# Edit data from form by selecting form through variable string

Tags: vb.net, forms

Is there any way this is possible:

```
 My.Forms(meCaller).TextBoxBranch.Text = TextBoxBranch.Text
```

Is there any code that can do what i am trying to do here?

Comment: meCaller is a string variable containing the form name

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
FormName.TextBoxBranch.Text = TextBoxBranch.Text
```

Comment: You must change the access Modifier of TextBoxBranch in the form you are accessing into public before you can do the above code.

Comment: yes, `TextBoxBranch` must be public to use it in another form.

Comment: Thanks, but i use different forms for the same purpose. That is why I want the form name to be variable..